# Size of div is not expanded automatically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div with `draggable`, `resizable` and `editable (contenteditable=true)` functionality. This div

contain some text in it, which user can edit. My problem is that when user write the text in the div, the div size

is not expand automatically. I set its `height:auto` but this also not works. What should i do so that while

entering the text the size of div also increases?

Comment: How does the div behave when you have more text that it's length can handle? It could be that you have any of the overflow or text-overflow options on.

Comment: currently i set its `overflow : visible`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about jQueryUI's resizable plugin, then that's your problem. It sets an explicit height on the element, overriding your `height: auto`.

Comment: Don't use resizable? Or listen to `keyup` events, and set the height on the element back to `auto`. The solution really depends on what compromises you're willing to make. But fundamentally, you can't say "this element can be manually resized but it also gets sized automatically".